# Passenger as Apache Module: Watchdog and Passenger Core running as root

Tags: passenger, phusion

On my unix box (Red Hat 6) I have Passenger set up to work as Apache Module. In the Passenger config I set `PassengerUser apache` to explicitly set my rails app to run as the *apache* user.

However, the *Passenger Watchdog* and *Passenger Core* processes run as root:

```
[root@myhost]# ps auxwf | grep -i  passenger
root     25157  0.0  0.0 365176  5992 ?        Ssl  12:36   0:00  \_ Passenger watchdog
root     25162  0.1  0.1 1417612 11852 ?       SNl  12:36   0:01  |   \_ Passenger core
apache   25227  0.0  1.4 506564 113520 ?       Sl   12:37   0:00 Passenger RubyApp: /var/www/myapp(production)
```

Is this as intended? I read in some bug reports that those processes are supposed to drop privileges once set up, but I cannot find any official statements regarding this. As virtually all unix distros start the main Apache process as root, these processes running as root might be correct in the first place, I am just wondering if there is any documentation that sheds light into this.

Comment: I have similar situation on `Ubuntu 16.04`.